# Check platform on Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

How can I check which platform (Windows / Windows Phone) my app is running?

Comment: https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/

Comment: In general, we recommend that you key off of the feature that your program needs, rather than the platform. If you want to know whether you are on a touch-first device, then use `UserInteractionMode`. That will let you provide a touch-first UI when running on a tablet (which is not a Phone). Also, it means that your program still behaves properly on Xbox and HoloLens and any future devices that support the universal Windows platform.

Comment: @Raymond Chen There are cases like a different rendering engine for WebView on Mobile, for example, when you just want to slap a dirty workaround till they fix the renderer. Sort of like the wild IE days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VersionInfo | versionInfo property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo.versioninfo?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) should helps to check the platform information.

```
    var str = Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily;
    if (str == "Windows.Desktop")
    {
      //...
    }
    else if (str == "Windows.Mobile")
    {
      //...
    }
```

Comment: This information is for analytics purposes (hence the name `AnalyticsInfo`). Programs should not be changing business logic based on the device family. You should check for the specific feature you need. The above code, for example, doesn't handle HoloLens or Xbox or any future device families.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the compiler directives

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE 
//some code
#endif

#if WINDOWS 
//some code
#endif
```