# Display a text box only in Windows 10 (desktop)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml

I just want to display a text box in Windows 10 (desktop) and I do not want that same text box to appear in Windows 10 Mobile. It's possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check platform on Windows 10 Universal App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404755/check-platform-on-windows-10-universal-app)

Comment: Also needs a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking for specific functionality over detecting OS.  Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation is your best option.

But if you only care if it is a phone look for something only a phone would have...  This is untested but you could do something like this:

```
    bool isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent =
    Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons");

if (isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent)
{
    // The true
}
```

Comment: But how do I relate this to the fact that I want the text box to appear only in Windows 10 (Desktop) and not in Windows 10 Mobile? This "connection" is what I can not do.

Comment: Set the Visible property of the textbox to the value of isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small method I use in my projects to check if my app is on **mobile**   or **not mobile**

```
public static bool IsMobile()  
{  
    String str = Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily;  
    bool _isMobile = (str == "Windows.Mobile") ? true : false;  
    return _isMobile;  
}
```

---

**Update:**

if you want to use in Code Behind,

```
textBox.Visibility = (IsMobile()) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
```

If you want to use through `DataBinding`, You can create a property and use the same logic to return `Visibility`

Comment: But how do I relate this to the fact that I want the text box to appear only in Windows 10 (Desktop) and not in Windows 10 Mobile? This "connection" is what I can not do.